# jquery get all parent and child elements of textarea input

Tags: jquery, find, parent

consider this html code

```
<textarea>
    <object>
      <embed></embed>
      <div></div
    </object>
</textarea>
```

If i issue the following jquery command

```
var x = $('textarea').val();
$(x).contents().andSelf().children().get()
```

i get an array with list of element inside the textarea. [embed, div], but i'm not getting the object tag.

Now if i issue the same jquery command on this

```
<textarea>
    <iframe>
    </iframe>
</textarea>
```

I get an error since iframe is a parent element and i get an error.

The point is to look inside the textarea val and find if a specific tag exists. I need to be able to search all parent and child elements of val.

```
TypeError: a.contentWindow is null
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the `object` in the first version? I only get `[<embed>​,<div>​</div>​]`, as I would expect because of `.children()`.

Comment: yes i get object in the array, because of `andSelf()`. Array looks like `[object, embed, div]`

Comment: Strange. Because of your `.children()` inclusion, you should only be getting the children of `[object, embed, div]`. Since `object` is the only one with children, that would give you `[embed, div]`.

Comment: I'm doing this in console. Textarea field is initially empty. I'm pasting the code inside it then issue jquery command in console. I'm not able to get it to work for iframe unless iframe is wrapped with another tag

Comment: @patrick Actually having a second look at this, i'm not able to get the object tag, i was able to get it in this example because it's wrapped with a div tag. What's the solution to get all tags including the parent. Since iframe i not wrapper with another tag, it's giving an error

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a clue. When I do `console.log($('<iframe></iframe>').contents());` I get an error. But if I append it to the `body` before doing `contents()` it works. `console.log($('<iframe></iframe>').appendTo('body').contents());`

Comment: @patrick Yes i get that too, but i don't want to append it before i do certain things to it.

Comment: I tried appending it to a newly created `documentFragment`, but that didn't seem to work. You may need to create a hidden container where you can do a temporary append.

Comment: I wonder if their are any other solution to this.

Comment: I even tried appending it then immediately removing it to see if it would give me any usable content. Didn't work. Seems like it needs to be attached to a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting issue. You may want to use contentEditable instead. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the children you have a specific selector:

`$('textarea > *')`

Try if that works